# Element type "textview" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, android, attributes, textview, element

The error is on the very last line.  and I have no idea what to do here or what code will work. If someoen can please show me what they did to resolve this I'd be happy.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jokeoftheday.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="@string/Your joke of the day is:"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:text="@string/The problem with twitter is that you always run out of chara-" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: your second TextView is not closed.

Comment: You're using `@string/` wrong. If you want to simply hardcode your values in, that's fine, but remove the `@string/` portion. You'll only use that if you're using a strings.xml file, and then you'd use the ID of the specified text

Answer (score 0):

Just compare what you have for the last textview to what you had in the textview about it.

See how before, you didn't have a ? You simply had /> at the end of all of your attributes. You need to change that last chunk to this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
android:text="@string/The problem with twitter is that you always run out of chara-" />
```

It's a very easy fix!

Hope that helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems

1. The text id's shall not contain "space" so "The problem...."
2. That is the main question, you are missing the "closing" for the

Note:

Both of the "end's" for the TextView are legal and working.